# which table updated after logout?

Tags: php, functions

I am working on wordpress in which on clicking logout button user will be logout using
`<?php wp_logout(); ?>` function
when I followed some guidelines on wordpress site I came to know that it actually delete all cookies 
but what about session and in database which table is updated , actually i am using buddypress to see currently active users
i got this code for destroying cookies.

```
function wp_clear_auth_cookie() {
    do_action('clear_auth_cookie');

    setcookie(AUTH_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    setcookie(SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    setcookie(AUTH_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, PLUGINS_COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    setcookie(SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, PLUGINS_COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);

    // Old cookies
    setcookie(AUTH_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    setcookie(AUTH_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    setcookie(SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    setcookie(SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);

    // Even older cookies
    setcookie(USER_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    setcookie(PASS_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    setcookie(USER_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    setcookie(PASS_COOKIE, ' ', time() - 31536000, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
}
```

please help,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't use sessions, and doesn't store any logged in information in tables.

It's all cookies, no tables are updated when a user logs out.